# Kiali install error on kubernetes on aws [error: unable to recognize "STDIN": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "v1"]

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kiali

I am trying to install kiali on kubernetes on aws. I followed the instructions at https://www.kiali.io/gettingstarted/. Got this error:

error: unable to recognize "STDIN": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "v1"

[image]

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the k8s install script was broken just yesterday, it should be fixed asap : https://github.com/kiali/kiali/pull/875

Comment: can you retry now?